# Trying to change element by Id - Not Working

Tags: javascript

I have tried various things, but I can't get the last three lines to work.

Any idea's why this will not change the font to red, italics, center align?

This is the first day of my course, I have no lecturer to ask, and there is no explanation given.

```
document.bgColor = "blue";
document.fgColor = "white";

var myDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
myDemo.innerHTML = Date();
document.getElementById("demo").fgColor = "red";
myDemo.fontStyle = "italics";
myDemo.textAlign = "center";
```

Comment: Is there an element with id "demo" on the page?

Comment: Show the html code specially the demo element.

Comment: `fontStyle` and `textAlign` are properties of `style` not directly of the element, try `myDemo.style.fontStyle = ..` and `fgColor` is deprecated, use `color` instead.

Comment: Thankyou Titus, that is what I needed to know. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The `fgColor & bgColor` properties are deprecated and not supported in all browsers. You could use `color & backgroundColor` properties to change the color and the background color.

All the `style` related properties belongs to the 'style' property of the element. We cannot set the css properties directly on the element. We have to set it on the element style property.

> **fgColor & bgColor**:
>   These feature are no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

```js
 document.body.style.color = "green"
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 function chnageColor() {
     var myDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
     myDemo.innerHTML = Date();
     myDemo.style.color = "red";
     myDemo.style.fontStyle = "italic";
     myDemo.style.textAlign = "center";
 }
```

```html
<div id="demo">  Some Text </div>
<button type="button" onclick="chnageColor()">Change color</button>
```

Comment: One more thing, document itself doesn't have a style property, you have to set it in body e.g. `document.body.style.color`.

Comment: There is also a `..bgColor = ..` in the OP's example, that can be replaced with `..backgroundColor  = ..`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `style` property of DOM object to access any styling attribute.

```js
var myDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
myDemo.innerHTML = Date();

myDemo.style.fontStyle = "italic";
myDemo.style.textAlign = "center";
```

```html
<div id="demo">Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in italics and also properties you trying to change are set in element.style instead of element itself.

```
document.bgColor = "blue";
document.fgColor = "white";

var myDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
console.log(myDemo);
myDemo.innerHTML = Date();
document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
myDemo.style.fontStyle = "italic";
myDemo.style.textAlign = "center";
```